# JW Player "setFullscreen"

Tags: jwplayer

i know this function (setFullscreen) is working only with HTML5, but it's not working for me. here is how i used:

```
setFullscreen: true
```

i want JW Player start in full screen right after the page loads. im testing it with chrome beta on android (HTML5).

Answer (score 3):

you can use get getFullscreen but for security there is no API call to set fullscreen

this gonna help :

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference#resize

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try this code: 
http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/using-the-browsers-new-html5-fullscreen-capabilities/

Answer (score 1):

you can use iframe

```
<iframe id="IVideo" runat="server" allowFullScreen="true" height="400px" width="480px"></iframe>
```

on server side...call another page that use Jwplayer

```
IVideo.Attributes["src"] = "Video.aspx?w=Video.mp4";
```